# Fullcalendar: How is possible to select multiple resource and days in timelive view

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I'm using fullcalendar and I need to let user select multiple rows for create a multi-resource event ([documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/resource_data/associating_events/)) but I not find how to do so. Anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say it's not supported. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selection/select_callback/ indicates that when a selection is made, the callback will return a single "resource" object which will indicate the resource chosen by the user. This implies that selecting multiple resources via dragging the mouse on the timeline is not possible.

You can create events via the "events" feeds which are associated with multiple resources (see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/resource_data/associating_events/) but it's not supported via the UI yet.

You'd have to create your own UI to allow the user to specify this, and/or put in a feature request to the maintainer to add this support in future (it may already be on the roadmap, I haven't looked).

Comment: Thanks, I add a feature request here: https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-scheduler/issues/310

Comment: intuitively, i would put a popup asking for other resurces to user into the select cb, and manually change the event's `resourceId` parameter to `resourceIds` with the array of those other resource's id as value.

Comment: @netalex good suggestion, I think that might be quite a neat way to do it. If you're feeling generous, you could make an alternative answer here with some code, or maybe stick a Gist on Github or something.

Comment: @ADyson i'm right in the way implementing it in my project now. when (and if) done, happy to post the code.

Comment: in the meantime, this answer will be useful (imagine the example with checkboxes for the resources) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12484742/how-to-use-jquery-dialog-with-fullcalendar-select-callback

Comment: I know this was years ago but @netalex did you ever figure out a way to implement this? I am stumped

Comment: @Enigmatical i'm very sorry, i think that project i was working on was abandoned before i could fix this.