# select multiple resources in fullCalendar

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

[excepted result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HZwe.jpg)

I want to select multiple resources in fullCalendar.

For example I would like to select all resources from Resource A to Resource D and duration 12pm am to 2.30 pm.

Is it possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fullcalendar: How is possible to select multiple resource and days in timelive view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43909082/fullcalendar-how-is-possible-to-select-multiple-resource-and-days-in-timelive-v)

Comment: See also the open issue https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-scheduler/issues/310